# Reading JSON in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, json

I have the newtonsoft library. I want to read email `id` and `name` from the following JSON string:

```
var InitialContacts = 
[
    {"guid":"","contactId":"32","contactName":"a, a a","email":"net.hitesh@gmail.com","isConnection":false,"connection":"","displayImg":null,"msgrID":"","msgrStatus":"","isMsgrBuddy":false},
    {"guid":"","contactId":"26","contactName":"bhaiya, manish","email":"yadavmanish_27@yahoo.co.in","isConnection":false,"connection":"","displayImg":null,"msgrID":"","msgrStatus":"","isMsgrBuddy":false}
]
```

How can I read it in ASP.NET?

Comment: Check this Blog it has a good example
[Example](http://encosia.com/2008/06/26/use-jquery-and-aspnet-ajax-to-build-a-client-side-repeater/)

Comment: I am using .NET 2.0 framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two solutions:

With JSON.Net you can create a class that matches the elements of the JSON string.  In this case  (Note - this is air code, haven't tested it):

```
public class TargetClass
{
  public string guid{get; set;}
  public int contactId{get; set;}

  ...
}
```

You can deserialize to a List.

Another way is to use the delimiters , & : and split the string into an array first by ",".  Then for each entry in the array, split again with the ":".

Comment: Note to the OP, you can use the approach that David describes to deserialize JSON with ASP.NET's JavascriptSerializer class too.  You need System.Web.Extensions installed (via ASP.NET AJAX Extensions 1.0) to use that in 2.0, but it's built-in in 3.5+.  So, code using that deserializer will require one less external dependency when eventually upgraded to 3.5 or 4.